# Problems using webpack and two.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, two.js

I am writing a web application using [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) and [two.js](https://two.js.org). For completeness, these are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
  "karma": "^1.7.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
  "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
  "karma-webpack": "^2.0.4",
  "webpack": "^3.5.5"
},
"dependencies": {
  "two.js": "^0.6.0"
}
```

I have the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './myentry.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'out')
    }
};
```

The entry file `myentry.js` just imports *two.js*:

```
import * as two from "two.js";
```

### Bundling succeeds...

Library *two.js* is part of my npm dependencies, so it can be found among my local node modules in `node_modules` folder. When I go ahead and create the bundle:

```
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

It **succeeds** and I get the following output:

```
Hash: 5e762def59fa65ff8487
Version: webpack 3.5.5
Time: 468ms
               Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  258 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
   [0] ./myentry.js 271 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1 hidden module
```

The generated bundle is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7YBzYyRhfbpbXhnM3o2STR0TnM/view?usp=sharing).

### But... running fails:

So I use the bundle in my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My stuff</title>
    <script type="module" src="./out/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

When I open the page in Chrome (I use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to avoid CORS related issues), I get these **errors in F12 Tools**:

```
bundle.js:1674 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Backbone' of undefined
    at bundle.js:1674
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1831)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.root (bundle.js:72)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:63)
    at bundle.js:66
```

What is happening?

Comment: What is `bundle-myentry.js`? Shouldn't it be just `bundle.js`?

Comment: Yes, in order to remove noise from original project I created a minimal working version, but copied stuff from wrong application... Just fixed

Comment: Its a little hard for us to help you if you dont post the full files. Giving us very little to work with here. Can you share a paste of the bundle file?

Comment: But the bundle is big, cannot paste it here... I am going to put it in some share and give the link...

Comment: Link added to the bundle that is generated. I have also added more info about the general setup with versions of my dependencies.

Comment: Looks like BackboneJS is required. You probably have to provide it as a plugin? https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/

Comment: I understand that this dependency is missing, but the library (two.js, I mean the doc) does not mention that. It is supposed to be self-consistent and provide all dependencies bundled. It does it with `underscore` for example

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is the way I am referencing the bundle in HTML:

```
<script type="module" src="./out/bundle.js"></script>
```

That is not correct as the generated bundle is not an ES6 modules :(

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="./out/bundle.js"></script>
```

This makes the error go away. It actually opens up to other errors, but they are completely unrelated to *backbone*.